# C# SQL wrong INNER JOIN data is being displayed don't know why

Tags: c#, sql

The problem I have is I've made a program where user may log in to check their account information (login with username and password from SQL database) however if I log in with details A then log out and Log in with details B. it will still display account information of User A but with User B log in details.

```
public string Username { get; set; }
```

//gets Username from Login form (another form)//

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Graded unit Dev\BlackMarch\BlackMarch\bin\Debug\DataBaseBM.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        /* (2) */
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT *
                                  FROM UserData
                                  INNER JOIN HotelData 
                                  ON (UserData.Username = HotelData.Username) ", con);




cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())

{

    txtboxPass.Text = dr["password"].ToString();
    txtboxFN.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    txtboxSurname.Text = dr["Surname"].ToString();
    txtboxAge.Text = dr["Age"].ToString();
    txtboxGender.Text = dr["Gender"].ToString();
    txtboxMobile.Text = dr["Mobile"].ToString();
    txtboxEmail.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();


    txtboxRoomType.Text = dr["RoomType"].ToString();
    txtboxNoRooms.Text = dr["NoOfRooms"].ToString();
    txtboxPackage.Text = dr["PackageDeal"].ToString();


    txtboxGym.Text = dr["Gym"].ToString();
    txtboxBeach.Text = dr["Beach"].ToString();
    txtboxPool.Text = dr["SwimmingPool"].ToString();
    txtboxSports.Text = dr["SportsGround"].ToString();
    txtDate.Text = dr["StartDateR"].ToString();

    strNoNights = dr["NoOfNights"].ToString();
    strNoDays = dr["NoOfDays"].ToString();
```

Comment: This query has no WHERE condition so your code gets all data produced by the JOIN but because your while loop replaces all the data from the previous loop with the current one you end up with your controls always showing the data of the last user read

Comment: Indeed - I see nothing to do with C# here, really... you'll see the same results if you perform that query directly in SQL Studio or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying the username in your query. A join will just return all the records for all users. If you want to get data for a specific user you need to use a parameterized query that passes in the name of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

This query has no WHERE condition so your code gets all data produced by the JOIN but because your while loop replaces all the data from the previous loop with the current one you end up with your controls always showing the data of the last user read

To fix you need to add a WHERE condition to your sql text in such a way that only the data of the current logged in user will be retrieved. From your code I don't know how do you store the username of the logged in user so let's assume that is stored in a variable named UserName

```
string cmdText = @"SELECT *
                   FROM UserData
                   INNER JOIN HotelData 
                      ON (UserData.Username = HotelData.Username) 
                   WHERE UserData.UserName = @user";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"....."))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserName;
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Now this will loop just one time, only for the logged in user
        while (dr.Read())
        {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to do it I tried but failed miserably with an error appearing "must declare scalar variable"

how I set username 

 public string Username { get; set; }
txtUsernameUser.Text = Username;

Comment: That's a strange error. The parameter is called `@user`. You need to set this parameter's value with the value of the property Username or the text of your control txtUsernameUser.

Comment: ExecuteReader is called before setting the username parameter. And please use the using statement as shown above. Using Statement is of utmost importance to avoid memory leaks on disposable objects like the connection, command and reader